# How can I run my Flask app step by step to debug it?

Tags: python, flask

I want to run IPython interactively while running my Flask app.  I tried `ipython -i app.py` but I don't get a prompt until after the app exits.  I want to do this so I can debug each step of the program.  How can I run my app and be able to examine it?

Comment: What's not working with `ipython -i app.py`? Is it displaying an error or anything?

Comment: Let me guess: The event loop of flask does not return and you won't get any prompt?

Comment: no it's not returning any error but after exiting from flask. It will return to ipython prompt.

Comment: @RahulKP That's is kinda point of `ipython -i`

Comment: @khajvah It's not a problem with the working of flask. Now i am doing image processing in python and it's GUI is designed in flask. So i need to know the each stage of process for my debugging. So your suggestions doesn't fit for the problem.

Comment: @RahulKP Use a debugger. What exactly do you expect from `ipython` ?

Comment: @khajvah if you run some of your code in Ipython like `ipython ` and in Ipython prompt `run -i code.py` you will get the Ipython prompt and inspect the variables in that code.

Comment: maybe try running it like this python app.py &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-i` flag runs the given program and then puts you in an interactive session *after it has run*.  There is no way to debug the program using this flag.

Instead, you want to use a debugger.  `python -m pdb app.py` will start [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), a console debugger.  There are other debuggers available, such as the graphical one built into IDEs such as PyCharm and PyDev, or more advanced console ones such as [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb).

Answer (score 0):

Implemented with `thread`

```
from flask import Flask                                                         
import thread
data = 'foo'
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return data
def flaskThread():
    app.run()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread.start_new_thread(flaskThread,())
```

And open the `IPython` Command prompt and type the command `run -i filename.py`